# How to represent large number in c++

Tags: c++, integer

I am trying to represent some large numbers in c++. In the below code if tried only to print `s` the compiler would not complain. But If try to make some multiplications and storing it in `t` the compiler would say `integer overflow in expression...`

I tried to make it `unsigned long long t` but again the compiler complains. Is there any way in doing this multiplication without having any overflow?

```
int main ()
{
    long long int s = 320718425168;
    long long int t = 4684688*68461; //4684688*68461 = 320718425168

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a "big number" library.  Tons of them exist if you really are going to work with numbers well beyond the `long long` range.

Comment: No I do not want to use any library(External library)

Comment: Then reimplement a bignum library..

Comment: @user3764893 - Well, if you plan on dealing with numbers that go out of bounds of an `unsigned long long` you have two choices -- either use a library or implement the code yourself.

Comment: What I am trying to say that, I don't want to download any libraries for that purpose. But if there are native libraries, then its OK

Comment: There is no "native" bignum library in the C++ standard.

Comment: Yeah, if you need a wheel to do the job, then you either need to use someone else's wheel or make one yourself.

Comment: @user3764893 - The answers below will work, provided you never get out of the range of the number type.  Again, if you do go out of range, then you have two choices (as mentioned in my comment above).

Comment: @user3764893 -- what is `native libraries` ? All libs are downloaded at some point and they may not all be installed by default.

Comment: @Soren you might be right. The below answer would be enough for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The literals used as the factors of the products are of type `int`, which cannot represent the product.

Cast one of the factors to `long long` first.

```
long long t = (long long)4684688 * 68461;
```

Or use the corresponding literal suffix `ll` or `LL` to change the literals type. I.e.

```
long long t = 4684688LL * 68461;
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eba7d5df0ff24356).